# How to analyze multi-plugin Eclipse RCP project with existing Ant build using Sonar?

Tags: ant, build, eclipse-rcp, sonarqube

Our Eclipse RCP project contains several plugins and has an existing Ant build using PDE build. I want to add Sonar to our build pipeline. I am aware that Sonar supports analyzing Ant builds in general with the Sonar Ant Task. I am looking for someone who has done this already for a multi-plugin Eclipse RCP application. The Sonar report should look like the report of a multi-module Maven project. Are there any templates/build scripts to copy from available?

Answer (score 1):

Here at SonarSource, we are analysing our Sonar Eclipse Plugins using a combination of Ant and Maven. Maybe this can help you: here are the sources => https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-eclipse